# Using Fluent nHibernate without primary/unique key column in the table

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my database table I don't have any primary or unique keys. I am using an Oracle database table.

1.Can I use Fluent nHibernate without primary or unique key?

2.If I can use it, how do I do the mapping? Because when `Id` is not mapped it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using oracle try to use "ROWID". But in my opinion If you don't have any primary or unique keys then better use your own ORM for your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [Fluent-NHibernate table mapping with no primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822966/fluent-nhibernate-table-mapping-with-no-primary-key?rq=1).

AFAIK all ORMs need a primary key. The main reason I see is to manage dirty tracking and caching mechanisms in session.

Also, there is no reason for you NOT to have a primary key in your table. Even if you think you don't need one, stick a auto incremented int column as the key and you should have no problems.

Comment: The thing is the database already exists and I am not allowed to do any changes to it.

Comment: I understand that. The thing is that some tools are built to work in a certain way and if don't have these prerequisites maybe this is not a tool you should use. Looks like you have a lot of constraints so maybe you are better suited with a Micro ORM like Dapper.